# get count of span tag within the first div alone using xpath

Tags: java, xpath, xpath-2.0

I want to get the count of  `<span class="show-for-sr">` within the first div alone.

My current xpath is returning count of the span across multiple div. I tried  below two xpath and they don't work. Why is that when I pass [1] to denote the first div it still gets count of the spans across all the div elements ?

1.

```
count(//div[@class='rating-container']//span[@class='show-for-sr'])
```

2. 

```
count(//div[@class='rating-container'][1]//span[@class='show-for-sr'])
```

**HTML :**

```
<div>
   <div class="cell small-12 medium-12 large-6">
      <div class="rating-container">
         <span class="text-blue-500 mr-8">
            <div class="tt-container"><button
               aria-label="open tooltip" class="button link" type="button" role="tooltip"
               aria-expanded="false">Morningstar rating</button></div>
         </span>
         <span><span
            class="icon fil-icon star-grey fil-icon-star-filled"><span class="show-for-sr">star-filled</span></span><span
            class="icon fil-icon star-grey fil-icon-star-filled"><span class="show-for-sr">star-filled</span></span><span
            class="icon fil-icon star-grey fil-icon-star-filled"><span class="show-for-sr">star-filled</span></span><span
            class="icon fil-icon star-grey fil-icon-star-filled"><span class="show-for-sr">star-filled</span></span><span
            class="icon fil-icon star-grey fil-icon-star-filled"><span class="show-for-sr">star-filled</span></span></span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="cell mb-32">
      <p class="intro morningstarInfo text-center-mob">Morningstar
         Rating<sup>TM</sup> (relative to category)
      </p>
      <table class="table striped" id="morningstar-info-table">
         <thead class="">
            <tr>
               <th scope="col" id="year" class="">Year</th>
               <th scope="col" id="morningstar return" class="">Morningstar return</th>
               <th scope="col" id="morningstar risk" class="">Morningstar risk</th>
               <th scope="col" id="morningstar rating" class="">Morningstar rating</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>3 - year</td>
               <td>High</td>
               <td>Low</td>
               <td>
                  <div class="rating-container"><span
                     class="text-blue-500 mr-8"> </span><span><span
                     class="icon fil-icon star-grey fil-icon-star-filled"><span
                     class="show-for-sr">star-filled</span></span><span
                     class="icon fil-icon star-grey fil-icon-star-filled"><span
                     class="show-for-sr">star-filled</span></span><span
                     class="icon fil-icon star-grey fil-icon-star-filled"><span
                     class="show-for-sr">star-filled</span></span><span
                     class="icon fil-icon star-grey fil-icon-star-filled"><span
                     class="show-for-sr">star-filled</span></span><span
                     class="icon fil-icon star-grey fil-icon-star-filled"><span
                     class="show-for-sr">star-filled</span></span></span></div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>5 - year</td>
               <td>High</td>
               <td>Low</td>
               <td>
                  <div class="rating-container"><span
                     class="text-blue-500 mr-8"> </span><span><span
                     class="icon fil-icon star-grey fil-icon-star-filled"><span
                     class="show-for-sr">star-filled</span></span><span
                     class="icon fil-icon star-grey fil-icon-star-filled"><span
                     class="show-for-sr">star-filled</span></span><span
                     class="icon fil-icon star-grey fil-icon-star-filled"><span
                     class="show-for-sr">star-filled</span></span><span
                     class="icon fil-icon star-grey fil-icon-star-filled"><span
                     class="show-for-sr">star-filled</span></span><span
                     class="icon fil-icon star-grey fil-icon-star-filled"><span
                     class="show-for-sr">star-filled</span></span></span></div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Overall</td>
               <td>High</td>
               <td>Low</td>
               <td>
                  <div class="rating-container"><span
                     class="text-blue-500 mr-8"> </span><span><span
                     class="icon fil-icon star-grey fil-icon-star-filled"><span
                     class="show-for-sr">star-filled</span></span><span
                     class="icon fil-icon star-grey fil-icon-star-filled"><span
                     class="show-for-sr">star-filled</span></span><span
                     class="icon fil-icon star-grey fil-icon-star-filled"><span
                     class="show-for-sr">star-filled</span></span><span
                     class="icon fil-icon star-grey fil-icon-star-filled"><span
                     class="show-for-sr">star-filled</span></span><span
                     class="icon fil-icon star-grey fil-icon-star-filled"><span
                     class="show-for-sr">star-filled</span></span></span></div>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
count(//div[@class='rating-container'][1]//span[@class='show-for-sr'])
```

use this

```
count((//div[@class='rating-container'])[1]//span[@class='show-for-sr'])
```

You should wrap entire div in indexing.